# How to check parameter condition in server side blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have an edit page to edit an employee in my server side blazor app. I get the user info from a UserManager by id which is passed to the site by a get parameter.

How can I do a check in my controller to verify that the user exists?
Here is my controller:

```
public partial class MitarbeiterEdit
{
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private UserManager<AppMitarbeiter> UserManager { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    private NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }


}
```

The page has the following path defined:

```
@page "/Admin/Benutzer/{Id:int}"
```

I was able to check the employee by overwriting the OnInitialized() method but this one throws an exception anytime I redirect.

Does anybody has an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnParametersSetAsync()` instead of `OnInitializedAsync()`